# Managed Package Yearly Security Review

Tags: security-review

I was under the assumption that after 1 year a managed package should again go thru security review.
However I published a free app that passed the security review at 26-1-2022. Since then I published few upgrades that automatically approved, as expected.
Today when I submitted a new released (17-2-2023) I was expecting that it will go thru full review, but it again approved automatically.

Is it ok? Can I know when it will go thru full review process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security Re-Review does not have a specific, defined timeframe. From the [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_periodic_reviews.htm):

> To identify which listed solutions are due for re-review, we consider potential risk and the amount of time since the solution was listed. To determine potential risk, we run risk-factor reports. If your solution shows significant change, it’s likely that we conduct a re-review. **The usual re-review timeframe is six months to two years after the solution was listed. However, if your solution’s risk factor is low, it may not be flagged for re-review.**

Emphasis mine.

Your experience may vary. Don't worry about it until you're asked to submit for re-review.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the security review process has some changes happening to it, specifically around fees - which appears to impact free app listings too. There will be a live Q&A session on 23th Feb at 08:30 PT. The meeting link is buried in the comments on [this partner forum posting](https://partners.salesforce.com/0D54V00006keZes) at the end of a comment from Shawna Moran.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I didn't know that. + the potential changes around the apps fees seems drastic. If indeed it will effect also free app it might remove any interest to publish such apps.